# Is there a way to get estimated time of completion of a currently running Informatica workflow in Infra metadata tables

Tags: metadata, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am working with this metadata table REP_WFLOW_RUN currently from Infra DB, to get status about workflows. The column run_status_code shows whether this wf is running, succeeded, stopped, aborted etc..

But for my Business use case I also need to report to Business, the estimated time of completion of this particular work flow.

Example: If suppose the workflow generally started at 6:15, then along with this info that work flow has started I want to convey it is also estimated to complete at so and so time.

Could you please guide me if you have any details on how to get this info from Informatica database.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very good question but no one can answer correctly :)
Now, you can get some logic like other scheduling tool does.

1. First calculate average time the workflow takes to complete for a successful run. And output should be a decimal value.

```
select avg(end_time - start_time )*24 avg_time_in_hr, workflow_name
From REP_WFLOW_RUN
Where run_status_code='succeeded'
Group by workflow_name
```

2. You can use above value as estimated time to completion for that workflow. Output should be a datetime.

```
Select sysdate + avg_time_in_hr/24 est_time_to_complete from dual
```

Now, this value is an estimated figure and not correct value. So on a bad day, if this takes hours, average value will be bad but we cant do much here.
I assumed, your infa metadata is on oracle.

Comment: Hello Kaushik, Yes our database is oracle. I have addressed the point to Business analysts , "Estimates time of completion" may not be accurate (if we calculate taking average run time from previous runs) as it may depend on workload of env that day or data volume being processed that day. But then they suggested as we are giving them "Estimated" time here it is ok if it's not too accurate. And Many thanks for your inputs above. :)

Comment: Hi @KaushikRoy I executed both the queries given above, and I get below inputs.  For avg_time_in_hr : 0,00319694694694694694694694694694694694684 and for next query the value est_time_to_complete: 13320612278945612278945612278945612278,5 I am not able to understand the values which have been retrieved actually. Could you explain a bit here.

Comment: the first output seems to be really high but it should be a decimal. but second output should be a date time. Can you pose what are start time and end time and avg_time_in_hr for a particular workflow.

Comment: This is how data looks like : wf_xyz  Start_date: 29-10-2021 06:16:56 End_date: 29-10-2021 06:24:09 I have 219 records for this workflow with different start time and end time. And the avg_time_in_hr value is 0,00319694694694694694694694694694694694684 for wf_XYZ

Comment: Hi @kaushikRoy, does this input helps you.

Comment: How can there be comma in the int data? Expected output will be nearly 0.13.

Comment: I added comments on how the values should be.